# Google Apps Script code for email sending automation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm hoping someone out here would help me on this. I'm not really a developer, but I figured my team and I would be able to utilize Google Apps Script for this as we use Workspace daily.

I'm not really good at descriptions so I apologize in advance, but here's the gist of it:

1. Trigger: New file is uploaded in Google Drive with a specific filename.
   *Example: ABC12345_RestoftheFilename.pdf;*
2. Code/Script will check a list (Google Sheet) that contains columns - code and email address/es.
   *Example:*

   | *Code*        | *Email Address*      |
   | *ABC12345*    | *email@email.com*    |
   | *DEF67890*    | *email1@email.com*   |
3. If the first 8 digits of the filename matches a code in the Code column the list, the code/script will send an email to the indicated email address in the list with the uploaded file in the Drive as attachment.

I've tried to search the internet for this however I can't seem to find it.

I've tried using this code, but an error in line 13 occurs: "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp."

```
function sendFileEmails() {
  // Replace the folder ID with the ID of the folder to monitor
  var folderId = "TestFolder";
  
  // Replace the sheet name with the name of the sheet to search for recipients
  var sheetName = "RecipientList";
  
  // Replace the email subject and message with your own
  var emailSubject = "New file uploaded!";
  var emailMessage = "A new file has been uploaded to the folder.";
  
  // Get the folder and its contents
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  
  // Get the sheet and its contents
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

  // Loop through each file in the folder
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    
    // Check if the file name starts with a specific letter or number
    if (/^[0-9a-zA-Z]/.test(fileName)) {
      // Search for a recipient in the sheet that matches the first letter or number of the file name
      for (var i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        var recipient = dataValues[i][0];
        if (recipient.substring(0, 1) === fileName.substring(0, 1)) {
          // Send an email to the matching recipient
          GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, emailSubject, emailMessage, {attachments: [file]});
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What does `Trigger` of `Trigger: New file is uploaded in Google Drive with a specific filename.` mean?

Comment: Does this error occur after changing `var folderId = "TestFolder";` to an actual ID? (The last long string of characters at the end of the folder's url.)

Comment: @Tanaike - Sorry for the confusion. It means that the script should run every time new file/s are uploaded in the dedicated folder.

Comment: @NEWAZA - I have to admit I am an idiot, I though it was the literal name of the folder and didn't even noticed it said ID. I've change it now though and tried to run it again. A new error came up - "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheetByName')"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Sorry for the confusion. It means that the script should run every time new file/s are uploaded in the dedicated folder.`, in your situation, how is the file uploaded? Because I think that the approach to achieving your goal depends on the method for uploading the file.

Comment: @Tanaike - It will be uploaded manually into the Drive because the file will come from a separate system.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did preface this by saying you aren't really a developer, and pasted in some code fresh out of ChatGPT, so no harm no foul.

To set this up, you will need to do a few things, first:

1. Create a new Spreadsheet file. The name is irrelevant.
2. In the top menu, select "Extensions" then "Apps Script".

Although the above code kind of works with what you're describing, try pasting in the code below:

```
const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

function runThisOneTime() {

  Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`).setName(`RecipientList`)

  Spreadsheet.insertSheet().setName(`Completed`)

  ScriptApp.newTrigger(`newFileAlert`)
           .timeBased()
           .everyMinutes(5)
           .create()

}


function newFileAlert() {

  // UPDATE VALUE
  const folderId = `UPDATE_THIS_VALUE_WITH_ID`

  const Recipients = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`RecipientList`)
  const RecipientData = Recipients.getDataRange().getValues()
  const Completed = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Completed`)  
  const CompletedFileData = Completed.getDataRange().getValues().flatMap(row => row[1])

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
  const files = folder.getFiles()

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    const file = files.next()
    const [fileName, fileId] = [file.getName(), file.getId()]
    
    if (!CompletedFileData.includes(fileId)) {

      const prefix = fileName.slice(0, fileName.indexOf(`_`))
      const recipients = RecipientData.filter(row => row[0] === prefix)
                                      .flatMap(row => row[1])
                                      .join(`, `)

      if (recipients.length) {
        
        // UPDATE VALUE
        GmailApp.sendEmail('UPDATE_THIS_VALUE_WITH_YOUR_EMAIL', `New file uploaded!`, `A new file has been uploaded to the folder:\n\n${file.getUrl()}`, {
            attachments: [file],
            name: 'Google Drive Alert', // UPDATE VALUE TO CHANGE DISPLAY NAME
            bcc: recipients
        })

        Completed.appendRow([new Date(), fileId, recipients])

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Be sure to quickly skim through and replace values if needed labeled "// UPDATE VALUE".

Next:

1. Save the code.
2. Run "runThisOneTime()".
3. Give the code access to run on your account.

This code will:

- Check the files of the specified folder every 5 minutes.
- Check if the file is listed in the "Completed" sheet.
- If not, it will gather the prefix and find all recipients associated with the prefix. ("PREFIX_filename.jpg")
- Attach the file and send to all matching recipients.
- Add the file to the "Completed" sheet.

This could probably be ran every 1 minute, but if the folder grows to a large quantity of files it might be a squeeze.

If you do want to try running it every minute, after running "runThisOneTime", go to the alarm clock icon, and find the edit icon on the right-side of the only item in the table. Towards the bottom you can change the time to "Every 1 minute".

Try this out and let me know if you have any other questions and beyond.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It worked! And yeah, I got it from ChatGPT. My apologies if I didn't mention it in my post.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it, feel free to reach out in the future if you have any adjustments you want to make. Nothing wrong with ChatGPT, just giving you a hard time. Best regards,